# Maya Bending in Blender, is it possible?

Tags: modeling, modifiers

current iam following a enviroment Tutorial, but the Teacher is using Maya. He bends a floor part with 15 degrees, when iam doing the same in Blender with the simpl deform Modifier, i dont get the same result. Is there a way to get same result as he got in maya?[image: His Result][image: MyResult]

Thanks for reading :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

-15 Z with object's origin at corner ...

[image]

... or place *Empty* at lower left corner and use as *Origin* object in modifier.

Comment: Thanks a lot that helped me :)

Answer (score 5):

An alternative to Vklidu's answer is the *Mesh > Transform > Bend*. Put the cursor at the bottom left:

[image]

Then put your mouse at the bottom right, <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>W</kbd> and drag:

[image]

Comment: OMG thats Awsome thanks a lot guys. I also found out, that i have to allign the mesh first to the 3D cursor where I want the pivot point and than set the pivot point to the 3D Cursor... If I set the pivot point first it will destroy the Mesh Dimension Inofrmation.